# How to give permissions to users without the admin web app

Tags: django, forms, permissions, models

I am currently trying to make a django form in order to give permissions to users. I have 4 different permissions for my Models: view, update, add and delete.
I would like to have kind of a checkbox system where for each Model, the administrators can select the permissions for a particular user

Let's say, I am using this kind of url: myapp/update/permissions/user/15
And I arrive on a page to select the permissions of user whose id is 15.
To make it simple, let's assume I have one model called 'Comment'. On this page I can choose whether the user can view, update, add or delete a comment. Of course, the administrators can select multiple checkboxes at once and the permissions the user has are already pre-checked.

Does anyone know how I could handle that?

Thanks a lot in advance! :)

PS: I know it is possible to give permissions to users via the admin app, but I want to have my own app to deal with that.

Comment: Create your own auth model, add fields like `can_update, can_delete...`. Write decorators that check that the user in request `can_update, can_delete...`.

Comment: The problem is that I still want to use Django permissions built-in system as much as possible. For each user, I want to use the field 'users_permissions'. And from my different models, I want to add permissions in their 'Meta' fields. With the method you propose, I need to add models, whereas I have the feeling everything is already there, I just need to glue everything together. Do you have another idea in this case? Thx!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a form in the template with the respective checkboxes and the in the view update the user permissions.

**form.html**

```
<form method='post'>
    <label for="add">Can Add</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="add" id="add" />
    <label for="change">Can Change</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="change" id="change" />
    <label for="delete">Can Delete</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="delete" id="delete" />
</form>
```

**views.py**

```
def form(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = request.POST
        if form.get('add'):
            if not user.has_perm('myapp.add_comment'):
                permission = Permission.objects.get(codename='add_bar')
                request.user.user_permissions.add(permission)
        if form.get('change'):
            if not user.has_perm('myapp.change_comment'):
                permission = Permission.objects.get(codename='change_bar')
                request.user.user_permissions.add(permission)
        if form.get('delete'):
            if not user.has_perm('myapp.delete_comment'):
                permission = Permission.objects.get(codename='delete_bar')
                request.user.user_permissions.add(permission)
return render(request, 'myapp/form.html', {})
```

For more info checkout :
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization

Comment: Thanks for your reply @sachiv-paruchuri. I like your way of achieving this. That's actually the first idea I had and that I started to implement.

However, there is a lot of manual work to do if there are a lot of different models we want to attach specific permissions to. Moreover, it is a constant work when new permissions appear.

Is there a way to automate this? With something like querysets? In order to fetch all the permissions related to the app and to display them automatically? (maybe by creating something in advance in forms.py?)
Thanks!